# PHP to rename uploads chronologically if same name exists

Tags: php

I currently have this script running to upload recordings from my smart phone app and it works great. But some users are not filling out their info completely and the uploads have  aname of "null" I want them to "If the upload name = null, then" rename them chronologically: null1, null2, null3, etc

But if their is no file currently in the folder with a matching name, then keep the uploaded name. Example, there could be john smith and john smith1, but no Jane Smith, so just keep the name. Here is my code

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "mp3/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
?>
```

Comment: This is a good read [What Have You Tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). Yes you showed us code, but what have you done to try to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
// Get the file name as an array
$file_name = explode('.', 'mp3/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

// Get the extension
$extension = array_pop($file_name);

// Get the file name as a string
$file_name = implode('.', $file_name);

// Set the initial suffix
$i = 0;

// Get the valid path
while (is_file($path = $file_name . ($i ?: '') . '.' . $extension))
{
  ++$i;
}

// Throw an exception if the file could not be moved
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path))
{
  throw new Exception('There was an error uploading the file.');
}
```